# Building query with NextJS, Prisma, and ClerkJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, clerk

I'm prototyping a project using NextJS, Prisma, and ClerkJS. I'm trying to understand how I would supply various params/props to my Prisma search clause. In particular I need to get the email address of a user from ClerkJS. This is my current index file:

```
import React from "react";
import prisma from "../../prisma/initPrisma"

const FacilitiesPage = ({ facilities }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.dashCards}>
      {facilities.map((facility) => {
        return (
          <div className={styles.card} key={facility.id}>
            <h4>{facility.name}</h4>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const facilities = await prisma.facility.findMany({
    where: {
      ownerEmail: 'harcodedemail'
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      facilities,
    },
  };
}

export default FacilitiesPage;
```

Obviously I can't hardcode the email address of every user in the system. ClerkJS offers [several ways](https://docs.clerk.dev/reference/clerk-react/useuser-hook) to query the user object and return various things from it, which I could pass into `getStaticProps` (or `getServerSideProps` probably). But nothing I've tried works. Candidly, I'm still learning the "React way" to do a lot of things.

TL;DR: how do I supply props to the query string in `getStaticProps`?

Comment: `getStaticProps` runs at build time on the server, it doesn't have access to request-specific data like a query string. You should either move that logic to the client-side, or use `getServerSideProps` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves ok, that's what I was slowly picking up on. I haven't found any solid examples of doing what I'm trying to do with `getServerSideProps`, including in the Prisma docs. Could you point me to a solid example? Thanks!

Comment: If your goal is to simply retrieve the query string, [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) provides a `context` object as parameter which contains a `query` field.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is inject into the query, using the email address of the currently logged in user to scope my query.

Comment: Clerk.dev posted this about SSR support on Aug, 2022 (answer is yes, they have a new component) https://clerk.dev/blog/next-js-ssr-authentication-with-clerk

Answer (score 2):

The folks at [Clerk.dev](https://clerk.dev) just answered this question. You need to use getServerSideProps and then use the new "withServerSideAuth" component. Here is a snippet from the blog post https://clerk.dev/blog/next-js-ssr-authentication-with-clerk :

```
import { withServerSideAuth } from "@clerk/nextjs/ssr";

export const getServerSideProps = withServerSideAuth(async ({ req, resolvedUrl }) => {
  const {sessionId,getToken} = req.auth;
 
    if (!sessionId) {
    return { redirect: { destination: "/sign-in?redirect_url=" + resolvedUrl } };
  }
    // use a token for your Clerk integrations
    const hasuraToken = await getToken({ template: 'hasura' });

    // retrieve data from your Hasura integration 
    
  return { props: {} };
});
```